Error OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound and 401 Unauthorized when Sending Email via Microsoft Graph API in React App
I'm working on a React app and attempting to send an email using Microsoft Graph API with OAuth2 authentication. However, when I try to send the email, I get a 401 Unauthorized error. Here's the flow I'm following:
User logs in using MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) and grants permissions for "Mail.Send" and "User.Read".
I acquire the access token via msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup().
I send an email via the Microsoft Graph API using axios.post() with the access token in the authorization header.
Here’s the error I am encountering:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail 401 (Unauthorized)
Error message:
Error during login or sending email: 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', ...}
Response error:
{error: {code: "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound", message: "The tenant for tenant guid 'd600ee99-eb85-4281-a0c5-18cc87425a9e' does not exist."}}
The response error indicates:

{ error: { code: "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound", message: "The tenant for tenant guid 'd600ee99-eb85-4281-a0c5-18cc87425a9e' does not exist." } }

I am using local user where UPN ends with .onmicrosoft.com to send the email.
I have tried:
Double-checking the permissions ("Mail.Send", "User.Read").
Ensuring the correct Microsoft tenant and subscription are being used.
Making sure the account is logged in and the token is acquired properly. i am attaching the api permissions screenshot.enter image description here
My code:
 export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "my-client-id", 
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenand-id>", 
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000", // Adjust as per your app
    },
  };

import React from "react";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { msalConfig } from "./msalConfig";
import axios from "axios";

const GraphApiTest = () => {
  const loginAndSendEmail = async () => {
    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    await msalInstance.initialize();

    try {
      // Login and acquire access token
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: ["Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
      });
      console.log("Login successful:", loginResponse);

      const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
      const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
        account,
        scopes: ["Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
      });

      const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      console.log("Access Token acquired:", accessToken);

      const emailPayload = {
        message: {
          subject: "Test Email from React App",
          body: {
            contentType: "Text",
            content: "This is a test email sent from my React app via Microsoft Graph API.",
          },
          toRecipients: [
            {
              emailAddress: {
                address: "gulzarjavaria2@gmail.com",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        saveToSentItems: "true",
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail",
        emailPayload,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      console.log("Email sent successfully:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login or sending email:", error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Response error:", error.response.data);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loginAndSendEmail}>Send Email via Outlook</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GraphApiTest;

heres the images for issue that email is not received: enter image description here enter image description here
Question:
Can anyone explain why I'm getting this "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" and "401 Unauthorized" error? The error message suggests there's an issue with the tenant ID. What steps should I take to resolve this issue and successfully send the email via Microsoft Graph API?

Could you include from what type of user account you are trying to send mail? Is it local user where UPN ends with .onmicrosoft.com or personal microsoft account? Please edit your question and add API permissions image from Portal

@Sridevi i am using local user where UPN ends with .onmicrosoft.com to send mail and i have also attached the api permissions image above

Could you include your msalConfig data too by editing your question to confirm what authority you are using?

@Sridevi i have added it above

Could you confirm whether your local user account has active Office 365 assigned or not?

@Sridevi no i don't have

To send mails using local user account via Microsoft graph, the user account must have active Office 365 license assigned that enables Outlook access to local tenant user.

To resolve the error, make sure to assign active Office 365 license to local tenant user account and rerun the code.

@Sridevi while trying to purchase office 365 license im facing this issue : "Please try again in a few minutes. We are unable to complete the verification check on your payment method at this time.  (CV: kMM+6nWPgxIzUMrV.67)" ,,i have tried adding 3 different cards still the same issue. can you help me with this?

Could you include how are you purchasing the license? Please edit your question and add images

@Sridevi i went to admin center and try purchasing Microsoft 365 Business standard for which im adding the images in above question please check them

Check if this helps https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-complete-the-verification-check-on-my/77cebce9-33ca-4581-94b8-f92728faa35c?page=4 Try purchasing the license from your mobile phone if browser not working.

@Sridevi i tried on mobile too still its not working now what i should do

Please raise a Microsoft Support request on this and get it resolved.

@Sridevi i have raised the request,,Thank you for your help,,i will contact again here if i need further assistance on this after this payment issue will get resolved

@Sridevi i just bought the license after the issue got resolved,,Now after that i am trying to login on outlook and the error that is appearing i will add it in the above question. Now its printed on console that email sent successfully but the email is not received in receiver's address,,Could it be due to the reason that i am not logged in on outlook??please check above question for images

Hi @JavariaGulzar please close this question here by clicking the checkmark beside it if it's helpful for you in any way and post a new question with more details and share link here

@Sridevi please checkout this question, need your kind cooperation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79255700/28546066

@Sridevi done that was very helpful,,please help me with the new problem too

Sure, will check tomorrow and add answer accordingly

@Sridevi  Sure, Thank you!!

Hi @JavariaGulzar Any update on new question ?

@Sridevi Hi,,I haven't tried it yet thank you so much for your answer on that i will try that and will let you know!!!

The error occurred as your user account does not have valid Microsoft 365 license assigned, that is required to send mails.
To resolve the error, make sure to assign active Microsoft 365 license to local user account like this:

In my case, I registered one application and granted same permissions as below:

When I ran react app with below code files by signing in with user having active Microsoft 365 license, I got response like this:
src/components/GraphApiTest.js:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { msalConfig } from "../msalConfig";
import axios from "axios";

const GraphApiTest = () => {
  const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState(""); // State to hold status messages

  const loginAndSendEmail = async () => {
    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    await msalInstance.initialize();

    try {
      // Login and acquire access token
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: ["Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
      });
      console.log("Login successful:", loginResponse);

      const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
      const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
        account,
        scopes: ["Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
      });

      const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      console.log("Access Token acquired:", accessToken);

      const emailPayload = {
        message: {
          subject: "Test Email from React App",
          body: {
            contentType: "Text",
            content: "This is a test email sent from my React app via Microsoft Graph API.",
          },
          toRecipients: [
            {
              emailAddress: {
                address: "sridevi.machaxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        saveToSentItems: "true",
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail",
        emailPayload,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      console.log("Email sent successfully:", response.data);
      setStatusMessage("Email sent successfully!"); // Update success message
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login or sending email:", error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Response error:", error.response.data);
        setStatusMessage("Failed to send email. Please try again."); // Update failure message
      } else {
        setStatusMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loginAndSendEmail}>Send Email via Outlook</button>
      {/* Display status message */}
      {statusMessage && <p style={{ marginTop: "20px", color: "green" }}>{statusMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GraphApiTest;

src/App.js:
import React from "react"; 
import GraphApiTest from "./components/GraphApiTest";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Send Email with Microsoft Graph API</h1>
        <p>
          Click the button below to log in and send an email via Microsoft Graph API.
        </p>
        <GraphApiTest />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

src/msalConfig.js:
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "appId", 
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId", 
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage", 
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
    },
  }; 

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in user's Sent Items where mail sent successfully as below:

Reference:
How can I fix Error: Code: OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound - Microsoft Q&A by Yakun Huang - MSFT
