Need admin approval unverified needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant
In my app i am trying to get the mail boxes of all the users registered in my users in azure portal using graph api and this is my code:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { msalConfig } from "./msalConfig";
import axios from "axios";

    const GraphApiTest = () => {
      const [inboxEmails, setInboxEmails] = useState([]);
      const [sentEmails, setSentEmails] = useState([]);
    
      const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    
      const loginAndFetchEmails = async () => {
        try {
          await msalInstance.initialize();
    
          const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    
          if (accounts.length === 0) {
            // No logged-in user, perform login
            await msalInstance.loginPopup({
              scopes: [
                "Mail.Read",
                "Mail.Send",
                "User.Read",
                "User.Read.All",
                "User-Mail.ReadWrite.All",
                "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared",
                "MailboxSettings.Read",
                "Mail.Read.Shared",
              ], // Required scopes
            });
          }
    
          const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0]; // Use the first account
          let tokenResponse;
    
          try {
            // Attempt to acquire token silently
            tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
              account,
              scopes: [
                "Mail.Read",
                "Mail.Send",
                "User.Read",
                "User.Read.All",
                "User-Mail.ReadWrite.All",
                "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared",
                "MailboxSettings.Read",
                "Mail.Read.Shared",
              ], // Required scopes
            });
          } catch (silentError) {
            // Fallback to interactive login if silent acquisition fails
            console.warn("Silent token acquisition failed, fallback to popup.");
            tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
              account,
              scopes: [
                "Mail.Read",
                "Mail.Send",
                "User.Read",
                "User.Read.All",
                "User-Mail.ReadWrite.All",
                "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared",
                "MailboxSettings.Read",
                "Mail.Read.Shared",
              ], // Required scopes
            });
          }
    
          const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
          console.log("Access Token acquired:", accessToken);
    
          // Fetch received emails (Inbox)
          const inboxResponse = await axios.get(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/example@visionx060.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders('inbox')/messages",
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              },
            }
          );
    
          // Fetch sent emails
          const sentResponse = await axios.get(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/example@visionx060.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders('sentitems')/messages",
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              },
            }
          );
    
          // Update state with emails
          setInboxEmails(inboxResponse.data.value);
          setSentEmails(sentResponse.data.value); // Sent emails
    
          console.log("Sent Emails:", sentResponse.data.value);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error during login or fetching emails:", error);
          if (error.response) {
            console.error("Response error:", error.response.data);
          }
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={loginAndFetchEmails}>Fetch Emails via Outlook</button>
    
          <h2>Inbox Emails</h2>
          <ul>
            {inboxEmails.map((email) => (
              <li key={email.id}>
                <strong>{email.subject}</strong> from{" "}
                {email.sender?.emailAddress?.address}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
    
          <h2>Sent Emails</h2>
          <ul>
            {sentEmails.map((email) => (
              <li key={email.id}>
                <strong>{email.subject}</strong> to{" "}
                {email.toRecipients
                  .map((recipient) => recipient.emailAddress.address)
                  .join(", ")}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default GraphApiTest;
    
    export const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
          clientId: "my client id", 
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>", 
          redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000", // Adjust as per your app
        },
      };

I have admin account and i granted following permissions in azure for this app: permissions screenshot
Still i am getting this window when a user other than admin try to fetch the mailbox of other users: the issue with user login
while the admin can get the other users mailbox without any problem. I want the same for other users too that they can get the other users mailboxes too.

In delegated scenarios, an app can access another user's mail folder only when the mail folder is shared or delegated access has been explicitly granted by the user. You can refer this MS Doc. Alternatively, switch to client credentials flow that uses permissions of Application type and can access mailboxes of all users.

@Sridevi its resolved now,,,Thank you so much!!!

@Sridevi now i am facing another problem with adding a filter on sent items in mail folder,,i have tried many solutions but it keep saying bad request,,the filter is working fine for the inbox but its not working fine for sent items,,here are my api calls for sent items and inbox in next comment

@Sridevi here it is:  const inboxResponse = await axios.get(
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages,
{
headers: {
Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken},
},
}
);
    // Fetch sent emails
    const sentResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('sentitems')/messages`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );


Hi @JavariaDulzar, it's not that clear in comments. Can you please post a new question with more details by including code and share that link here?

hi @Sridevi please checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79264017/28546066

Hi @JavariaGulzar Added answer to your new question. Please check and let me know if it works : )

@Sridevi its solved,,Thank you so much!!!

Glad to know it worked : )

Initially, I too got same error when an non-admin user tried to access mails of other user in delegated scenario without shared access:

In delegated scenarios, app can access mailboxes or resources for which the signed-in user has permissions, such as their own mailbox, shared mailboxes, or mailboxes that the user has explicitly granted access to (via delegation).
To allow non-admin users to access other users' mailboxes without needing delegation or sharing, you need to switch to application permissions and use the client credentials flow.
In my case, I registered one application and granted Mail.Read permission of Application type with consent as below:

Now, I created one Node.js backend server project and installed dependencies in it with below commands:
mkdir email-fetcher-backend
cd email-fetcher-backend

npm init -y
npm install express axios body-parser dotenv

Later, I added below code files to store credentials and fetch emails with token generated using client credentials flow:
.env:
TENANT_ID=tenantId
CLIENT_ID=appId
CLIENT_SECRET=secret_value

server.js:
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const tenantId = process.env.TENANT_ID;
const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

// Fetch Access Token using Client Credentials Flow
const getAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    }));
    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting access token:', error);
    throw new Error('Unable to get access token.');
  }
};

// Fetch Emails (Inbox and Sent Items) from Microsoft Graph
app.get('/emails', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();

    // Fetch inbox emails
    const inboxResponse = await axios.get(
      'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages',
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    // Fetch sent items emails
    const sentResponse = await axios.get(
      'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/sentitems/messages',
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    // Format inbox emails as per the required format
    const inboxEmails = inboxResponse.data.value.map(email => ({
      subject: email.subject,
      sender: email.sender.emailAddress.address,
    }));

    // Format sent emails as per the required format
    const sentEmails = sentResponse.data.value.map(email => ({
      subject: email.subject,
      to: email.toRecipients.map(recipient => recipient.emailAddress.address).join(", "),
    }));

    // Send the formatted data back to the frontend
    res.json({
      inbox: inboxEmails,
      sent: sentEmails,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching emails:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Failed to fetch emails.');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

When I run the server with node server.js command and visited http://localhost:5000/emails in browser, I got mails successfully like this:

Reference:
List messages - Microsoft Graph v1.0
