How to apply filter on sent items in Graph API
This is my code file where I am trying to add filters on inbox and sent items using Microsoft graph API:
const GraphApiTest = ({ email }) => {
  const emailsPerPage = 5;
  const [inboxPage, setInboxPage] = useState(1);
  const [sentPage, setSentPage] = useState(1);
  const [inboxEmails, setInboxEmails] = useState([]);
  const [selectedEmail, setSelectedEmail] = useState(null);
  const [sentEmails, setSentEmails] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState("");
  const [emailsData, setEmailsData] = useState({});
  const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  const users = [
    "user1@example.onmicrosoft.com",
    "user2@example.onmicrosoft.com",
    "user3@example.onmicrosoft.com",
  ]; // Add the user emails here
  useEffect(() => {
    if (email) {
      loginAndFetchEmails();
    }
  }, [email]);
  const loginAndFetchEmails = async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.initialize();
      const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
      if (accounts.length === 0) {
        await msalInstance.loginPopup({
          scopes: ["Mail.Read", "Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
        });
      }
      const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
      let tokenResponse;
      try {
        tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
          account,
          scopes: ["Mail.Read", "Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
        });
      } catch (silentError) {
        console.warn("Silent token acquisition failed, fallback to popup.");
        tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
          account,
          scopes: ["Mail.Read", "Mail.Send", "User.Read"],
        });
      }
      const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      setLoading(true);
      // Fetch received emails (Inbox)
      const fetchedEmails = {};
      for (const user of users) {
        const inboxResponse = await axios.get(
         `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq '${email}'`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        }
        );
      // Fetch sent emails
      const sentResponse = await axios.get(
        `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('sentitems')/messages`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
      fetchedEmails[user] = {
        inbox: inboxResponse.data.value,
        sent: sentResponse.data.value,
      };
    }
    // Update state with emails for all users
    setEmailsData(fetchedEmails);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login or fetching emails:", error);
    } finally{
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const paginateEmails = (emails, page) => {
    const start = (page - 1) * emailsPerPage;
    const end = start + emailsPerPage;
    return emails.slice(start, end);
  };
  const inboxEmailsPaginated = paginateEmails(inboxEmails, inboxPage);
  const sentEmailsPaginated = paginateEmails(sentEmails, sentPage);
  const totalInboxPages = Math.ceil(inboxEmails.length / emailsPerPage);
  const totalSentPages = Math.ceil(sentEmails.length / emailsPerPage);
  const openModal = (email) => {
    setSelectedEmail(email);
  };
  const closeModal = () => {
    setSelectedEmail(null);
  };
  
export default GraphApiTest;

In this code when I am adding filter on inbox folders its working fine and giving me the filtered emails from that email address but for sent items when I try this:
const sentResponse = await axios.get(
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders/sentitems/messages?$filter=toRecipients/any(t:t/emailAddress/address eq '${email}')`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  }
);

It gives the error 400 and says invalid uri. How can I add a filter on sent items folder too? I have tried many ways but whenever I add a filter on sent items it always gives error while for inbox it works fine. Here is the error message:

and this error on console:

response
:
"{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"There is an unterminated string literal at position 34 in '\"recipients:example@gmail.com'.","innerError":{"date":"2024-12-09T06:49:41","request-id":"61e6203d-db9f-4948-85e8-d41ddf5db99a","client-request-id":"61e6203d-db9f-4948-85e8-d41ddf5db99a"}}}"
responseText
:
"{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"There is an unterminated string literal at position 34 in '\"recipients:example@gmail.com'.","innerError":{"date":"2024-12-09T06:49:41",


Could you edit your question and add complete error message?

@Sridevi i have added the picture

The toRecipients property doesn't support filtering, but you can use $search query parameter and search for messages by recipients
const sentResponse = await axios.get(
  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders/sentitems/messages?$search="recipients:${email}"`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  }
);


I agree with @user2250152, filtering on toRecipients property is not supported. Alternatively, make use of $search query parameter.
In my case, I used below code files in react app to generate access token and filter retrieved emails:
GraphApiTest.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'appId',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
};

const GraphApiTest = ({ email }) => {
  const emailsPerPage = 5;
  const [inboxPage, setInboxPage] = useState(1);
  const [sentPage, setSentPage] = useState(1);
  const [inboxEmails, setInboxEmails] = useState([]);
  const [sentEmails, setSentEmails] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const msalInstance = useMemo(() => new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig), []);
  const users = useMemo(() => ['sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'], []);

  const paginateEmails = (emails, page) => {
    const start = (page - 1) * emailsPerPage;
    const end = start + emailsPerPage;
    return emails.slice(start, end);
  };

  const loginAndFetchEmails = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.initialize();
      const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
      if (accounts.length === 0 && msalInstance.inProgress !== 'login') {
        await msalInstance.loginPopup({
          scopes: ['Mail.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'User.Read'],
        });
      }

      const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
      let tokenResponse;
      try {
        tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
          account,
          scopes: ['Mail.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'User.Read'],
        });
      } catch (silentError) {
        console.warn('Silent token acquisition failed, fallback to popup.');
        tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
          account,
          scopes: ['Mail.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'User.Read'],
        });
      }
      const accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
      setLoading(true);

      const fetchedInboxEmails = [];
      const fetchedSentEmails = [];
      for (const user of users) {
        const inboxResponse = await axios.get(
          `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq '${email}'`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          }
        );

        const sentResponse = await axios.get(
          `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${user}/mailFolders('sentitems')/messages?$search="recipients:${email}"`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          }
        );

        fetchedInboxEmails.push(...inboxResponse.data.value);
        fetchedSentEmails.push(...sentResponse.data.value);
      }

      setInboxEmails(fetchedInboxEmails);
      setSentEmails(fetchedSentEmails);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during login or fetching emails:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [email, msalInstance, users]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (email) {
      loginAndFetchEmails();
    }
  }, [email, loginAndFetchEmails]);

  const inboxEmailsPaginated = paginateEmails(inboxEmails, inboxPage);
  const sentEmailsPaginated = paginateEmails(sentEmails, sentPage);
  const totalInboxPages = Math.ceil(inboxEmails.length / emailsPerPage);
  const totalSentPages = Math.ceil(sentEmails.length / emailsPerPage);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      <div>
        <h3>Inbox</h3>
        <ul>
          {inboxEmailsPaginated.map((emailItem) => (
            <li key={emailItem.id}>
              {emailItem.subject}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={() => setInboxPage(inboxPage - 1)} disabled={inboxPage === 1}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setInboxPage(inboxPage + 1)} disabled={inboxPage === totalInboxPages}>
          Next
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>Sent Items</h3>
        <ul>
          {sentEmailsPaginated.map((emailItem) => (
            <li key={emailItem.id}>
              {emailItem.subject}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={() => setSentPage(sentPage - 1)} disabled={sentPage === 1}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setSentPage(sentPage + 1)} disabled={sentPage === totalSentPages}>
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GraphApiTest;

App.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GraphApiTest from './GraphApiTest';

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [submittedEmail, setSubmittedEmail] = useState('');
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEmailSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (email && email.includes('@')) {
      setSubmittedEmail(email);
      setIsSubmitted(true);
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a valid email address!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <h1 style={styles.header}>Microsoft Graph API - Email Fetcher</h1>
      
      <form onSubmit={handleEmailSubmit} style={styles.form}>
        <div style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <label htmlFor="email" style={styles.label}>Enter email to filter mails:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={handleEmailChange}
            placeholder="Enter email to filter mails"
            style={styles.input}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" style={styles.button}>Fetch Emails</button>
      </form>

      {isSubmitted && submittedEmail && (
        <GraphApiTest email={submittedEmail} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    maxWidth: '800px',
    margin: '0 auto',
    padding: '20px',
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  },
  header: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: '20px',
  },
  form: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    marginBottom: '20px',
    width: '100%',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: '16px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    display: 'block',
    marginBottom: '10px',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: '10px',
    fontSize: '16px',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0078d4',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    padding: '10px 20px',
    fontSize: '16px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    transition: 'background-color 0.3s',
  },
  buttonHover: {
    backgroundColor: '#005a9e',
  },
};

export default App;

Output:

When I visited http://localhost:3000/ in browser and clicked Fetch Emails button after entering email, it asked me to sign in first and retrieved filtered mails successfully as below:


"{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"There is an unterminated
string literal at position 34 in '"recipients:example@gmail.com'."

In your case, the above error occurred because the $search query value was not properly enclosed with the correct quotes leading to an unterminated string literal error.
To resolve this, please ensure that the $search query value is correctly framed like this:
$search="recipients:${email}"

This will properly enclose the value in double quotes and avoid the unterminated string literal error.
